# How to add a plot to a figure (matplot.lib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

```
teamDamageAdata = self.getTeamsDamage("A")

teamDamageA = plt.figure(figsize=(100, 100), dpi=1)
plt.style.use('dark_background')


teamDamageAdata = pd.DataFrame(teamDamageAdata)
teamDamageAdata.plot(kind="barh", color=("w","r","b"), legend=None, stacked=True, mark_right=True)

plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show() #screenshots with and without

teamDamageALabel = FigureCanvasTkAgg(teamDamageA, master=Stats)
```

matplot output: (good)

[image]

tkinter output: (missing plot)

[image]

My goal is to get the output seen in matplot into tkinter. however, I could not find a way to add teamDamageAdata plot to the teamDamageA figure.

I would be glad if anyone could point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

teamsDamageAdata sample format = {'true': [1041], 'physical': [913], 'magic': [6512]}

I have read through the documentation .plot() method and tried this:

```
teamDamageAdata = self.getTeamsDamage("A")
print(teamDamageAdata)

teamDamageA = plt.figure(figsize=[400, 50], dpi=1)
plt.style.use("dark_background")


teamDamageAdata = pd.DataFrame(teamDamageAdata)
plt.plot(data=teamDamageAdata, kind="barh", color=("w","#b20000","#50A6C2"), legend=None, stacked=True, mark_right=True)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show() this now also returns a blank image in matplot like seen earlier in tkinter

teamDamageALabel = FigureCanvasTkAgg(teamDamageA, master=Stats)
```

I have also tried:

```
teamDamageAdata = self.getTeamsDamage("A")
print(teamDamageAdata)
    
teamDamageA = plt.figure(figsize=[400, 50], dpi=1)
plt.style.use("dark_background")
    
    
teamDamageAdata = pd.DataFrame(teamDamageAdata)
plt.plot("xlabel", "ylabel", data=teamDamageAdata, kind="barh", color=("w","#b20000","#50A6C2"), legend=None, stacked=True, mark_right=True)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show()
    
teamDamageALabel = FigureCanvasTkAgg(teamDamageA, master=Stats)
```

Adding x and y label causes an error:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized character l in format string
```

I feel like I made a step in the right direction but one change returns a blank plot without errors and the other is with labels but has an error. I've tried looking around for what this error is and could not find anything.

[EDIT 2]:
I have used a similar method to plot pie charts earlier, which works. But I cannot see what is different with the graph.

```
damagePieChart = plt.figure(figsize=[75, 75], dpi=1)
damagePieChart.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:black')

slices = self.getPlayerDamage(participant)
colors = ["white", "#b20000", "#50A6C2"]
plt.pie(slices, startangle=90, colors=colors, counterclock=False)
plt.tight_layout()
damagePieChartLabel = FigureCanvasTkAgg(damagePieChart, master=Stats)
```

[image: damage pie charts]

Comment: Rather than using the `pyplot` interface, use the object-oriented interface so that you can be 100% sure that `teamDamageAdata.plot` acts on an Axes contained by `teamDamageA`

Comment: See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#usage-patterns for more info

Comment: you might also try removing the call to `plt.show()`

Comment: plt.show() is in there to see if the plot works in matplot before I try it in tkinter, when I run it for tkinter I comment it out